# Input text on every key up in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I' new to chrome extension and I would like to know if its feasible to

Write a chrome extension to get an input value without any browser actions or context menus. 
What I'm trying to achieve is

1. Get the input text from any website based on the id on every key down/up event (the text id can be different for different websites) into the content script
2. Pass the input text on every keyup/down to a server to search for the content
3. return the results back to content script (don't know if background script is needed)
4. display the result into an autocomplete list

I have the scripts for autocomplete, but I still can't figure out how to get the extension

Can someone point me to the right direction? or if this is feasible in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

In your `manifest.json`: specify a content script that matches all URLs and a background script.

In your `background script` setup a message listener that talks to your server and sends the results back as a reply to messages.

In your `content script` select the inputs you want to listen to and add change listeners. In your change handling function send a message to your background scrip then when you receive the reply add the list to the input.

Resources you should look at:

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging